# Altering a function property inside a new function

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I am trying to create a Global function, which I can use in another function , retrieve the inner functions of that function and modifying the properties inside another function as because this function is needed to call in various functions later on. I am trying but it is not working. Somehow, I am going wrong. 
My Global Function is which is in **"a.js"** file

```
var DefaultDamiracleScripts = function(){

return {
    AllimagesLoaded : function( $container ) {
        this.ImageLoad = function( innerfunctions ) {
            $( $container )
                .imagesLoaded( 
                    { 
                        background : true 
                    }, 
                    function(){
                        console.log( $( $container ).attr( 'class' ) );
                        var innerfunctions = function() {
                            alert('hi');
                            //return true;
                        };
                    }
                );

                return{
                    innerfunctions : innerfunctions
                }
            };

            this.innerfunctions = this.ImageLoad.innerfunctions;

            if ( $container ) {
                return this.ImageLoad();
                return this.innerfunctions();
            }
        }//AllimagesLoaded
    }
}();
```

Now in my **"b.js"** I am calling the function and trying to modify
the "innerfunction" property, so that I can play with this function 
property multiple times by adding functions and some private variables
inside it whenever necessary which I am writing:

```
var SliderPreloaderAction = function() {
    var sliderImageLoad = new DefaultDamiracleScripts.AllimagesLoaded( '#homeBannerSlider' );

    //Just checking whether it works
    sliderImageLoad.innerfunctions();
};

SliderPreloaderAction();
```

I find innerfunctions() is not working here
I am also not getting any console error

Can anyone please help me in this regard
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you like this namespace syntax `DefaultDamiracleScripts.AllimagesLoaded` - then the `DefaultDamiracleScripts` should be an object, not a function. Like this: `var DefaultDamiracleScripts = { AllimagesLoaded : function( $container ) { ... } }`; BTW using namespace-like syntax like this is just ***enough*** to organize your code. Don't try to complicate things like inventing some `nested function` (meaning function declared inside function), ... that's just useless. Of course anonymous functions can be used anywhere, but named functions should be declared globally or in some namespace.

Comment: `var innerfunctions = function() ...` is local to the function and you are trying to access it outside at `return{ innerfunctions : innerfunctions}` which actually is returning the argument `innerfunctions` which you are passing to your function. Your function argument and local variable has same name. Why ?